# Reading multiple zipped files in awk script

Tags: awk, gzip

I have an awk script named `text_processing.awk` . I need to pass multiple zipped files named `01JAN21.txt.gz` , `02JAN21.txt.gz` etc. to this script for further processing. The output file takes the date from the input file and gets named `result_01JAN21.txt` and so on.

Please note the files are zipped.

I tried running on one file at first using command below

`zcat 01JAN21.txt.gz | awk -f text_processing.awk -`

However, my output file doesn't get named, I believe because this command just opens the file and pipes it to the script, whereas, my script extracts date from the input file name as below

```
BEGIN{ 
  FS = ";" 
  input_file = ARGV[1] 
  sub(/\.txt\.gz/, "", input_file) 
  output = "result_" input_file ".txt 
}
```

Will appreciate some guidance on how to go about rectifying it. I want to keep the renaming of output file within awk script because there are multiple files I will be passing at one go.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to process all files in the current directory that have names matching `*.txt.gz`.  Pass the name as a variable into `awk` and stream the uncompressed data:

```bsh
for name in *.txt.gz; do
    gzip -c -d -- "$name" |
    awk -v name="$name" -f text_processing.awk
done
```

In the `awk` code, you'd use the `name` variable to compute the output filename.

Alternatively, get the shell script to give you the explicit output filename to use:

```bsh
for name in *.txt.gz; do
    gzip -c -d -- "$name" |
    awk -v outname="result_${name%.gz}" -f text_processing.awk
done
```

The string `result_${name%.gz}` would be the name of the original file with `.gz` removed and `result_` prepended.  The `awk` code then uses `outname` to write to.

Obviously, if your `awk` code only writes to a single output file, you may simplify the `awk` code even more and have it just print to its standard output.  Then do the output redirection in the shell:

```bsh
for name in *.txt.gz; do
    gzip -c -d -- "$name" |
    awk -f text_processing.awk >"result_${name%.gz}"
done
```

---

Extra material requested in comments:  Running the `awk` command in parallel.

For this, I'm going to use `xargs`, and I will assume that this utility supports the non-standard options `-0` (for reading nul-terminated data), `-r` (for not executing the given command if there is no input), and `-P` (for running jobs in parallel).

```bsh
print '%s\0' *.txt.gz |
xargs -0r -P 4 -I {} sh -c '
    gzip -c -d -- "$1" |
    awk -f text_processing.awk >"result_${1%.gz}"' sh {}
```

This would run the `gzip`+`awk` pipeline for four files concurrently. Add `-t` to the `xargs` utility's options to get and indication of what commands it is spawning.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. Adding to this query, how can I modify your command if I want to run the files/script in parallel?

Comment: @L1971 That's a very different question. You may want to search this site for [parallel processing files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=parallel+processing+files).  I might add something to my existing answer later when I get some free time from my day job.

Comment: @L1971 See added bit at the end.

Comment: @L1971 [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and asking multiple different questions at once are strongly discouraged. You got a good answer to the question you asked so you should accept it and  ask a new question about how to run scripts in parallel if you also need help with that.